# How to use the if-else statement for querying on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm making a request to my database, but I have no clue how to use the if-else statement if no records are found.

```
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        const results = await pool.request().query(`SELECT * FROM usersAPI where id = ${userID}`)
        return results.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I've done my research but I don't know if using and if-else statement direct from the query will be useful.

Can someone guide me please?

Getting knowledge of SQL Server and NodeJS

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const results = await pool.request().query(`SELECT * FROM usersAPI where id = ${userID}`);

    if (results.recordset.length > 0) {
        // Records were found, process the records
        return results.recordsets;
    } else {
        // No records were found, handle the case accordingly
        console.log('No records found for the given userID');
        // Handle the case where no records were found, such as returning an appropriate response
      }
    } catch (error) {
    console.log('An error occurred:', error);
    // Handle the error, such as returning an error response or throwing an exception
}
```

Comment: YEEEEEEES THAT'S WHAT I WANT IT!!! THAN YOU

Comment: im very sorry, since im kind of new here, i  need a reputation of 15, i have 11, but... IF YOUR STUCK LIKE ME, THE ANSWER OF RIZATZMI IS THE ANSWER!! PLEASE GIVE HIM A VOTE